# Does Quarkus support multiple AWS Lambda handlers in one project?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, quarkus, aws-serverless

I’ve found several nice examples of Quarkus projects which enable easy declaration of Lambdas in a project, usually also using AWS SAM, which is great. However, none of them (or any docs, that I could find) show support for multiple Lambda handlers in one project without having to choose a single Lambda to deploy.

The use case I’m looking for is a basic REST API offering CRUD methods (one handler per HTTP verb) where the SAM template declares a new Lambda for each handler.

Is this really not supported yet by a Quarkus library/extension, or is documentation just ambiguous about it?

Comment: Not answering your questions but I suggest using JAX-RS (Resteasy) over AWS Lambda for this kind of stuff, it'll be easier to implement and portable over cloud provider. This is documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http

Comment: how would he deploy this REST api, if the requirement is to deploy  as AWS Lambda function? how whole REST Api could wrap to single lambda function to be deployed as lambda

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definitive answer but as far as I know, quarkus will make you choose a single lambda handler for a build.

For your use case though, you can simply create a single quarkus application with multiple jax-rs endpoints offering the required CRUD methods, and then use the quarkus extension "quarkus-amazon-lambda-http" (for deploying as AWS API Gateway HTTP api) or "quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest" (for deploying as AWS API Gateway REST api) for building your application which will allow quarkus to generate the required SAM template for API Gateway to invoke the corresponding jax-rs endpoint (as a new lambda invocation) per HTTP path and verb.